# Компиляция TypeScript и выполнение созданного js в Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text

Я хочу в Sublime Text 3 компилировать .ts текущий файл и выполнять созданный .js файл с помощью node, что я делаю не так?

```
{
    "cmd": ["tsc", "$file_name", "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe", "${file_base_name}.js"] ,
    "selector": "source.ts",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А может не мудрить?

```
npm i -g ts-node
```

И запускаешь не через `node`, а через [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node).

Comment: а я бы ещё хотел, чтобы создавался файл, есть какие-то флаги для ts-node для создания js файла?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, не думаю. Файл можно скомпилировать через tsc, но там ещё пачка параметров может понадобиться. А смысл иметь скомпилированный файл, если и так работает?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы выполнять .ts файл в Sublime Text 3 нужно установить пакет `ts-node`:

```
npm install -g ts-node
```

Создать новую сборку Sublime-buid и прописать в ней(для Windows 10 работает):

```
{
    "cmd": ["ts-node", "$file"],
    "shell": true
}
```